# What is the use of "bookkeeper" field in Metaplex Auction House receipts

Tags: metaplex

Metaplex Auction House has three kinds of receipt: BuyReceipt, ListingReceipt and PurchaseReceipt.

Each of the three has a field called "bookkeeper".

Some fees are deducted from the bookkeeper account every time a receipt of each type is created.

What is the use of this field? Is it for information only / i.e. partitioning the data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bookeeper is the wallet that paid for the receipt. It's only responsibility at this time is tracking the payer of the receipt so that in the future if the account is allowed to be closed the program knows who should be refunded for the rent.

Answer (score 0):

The bookkeeper field is used to track the person responsible for keeping track of the auction house's finances. This information is used by the auction house to ensure that the person responsible for the auction house's finances is able to keep track of the auction house's income and expenses.

Comment: I’m looking for a bit more technical detail - how does this relate to the underlying rust contacts? Does it have meaning in terms of logic or is it a data partitioning device etc?